# I am unable to connect to rabbitmq server in docker

Tags: java, scala, docker, rabbitmq, sbt

I am using docker compose to run a sbt process which connect to rabbitmq-server . Following is my docker compose file : -

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: abhishekkumargaya/messanger
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
    links:
      - rabbit-server
      - redis
      - mysql
    networks:
      - webnet
  rabbit-server:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: localhost
    environment:
      #RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER : guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS : guest
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"

    networks:
      - webnet

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: database.dev
    command: mysqld --user=root --verbose

    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "user_messages"
      MYSQL_USER: "test"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"

networks:
  webnet:
volumes:
  redis-data:
```

I am getting connection refused error. I am using default value to connect to rabbit server in my code .

```
private lazy val factory = new ConnectionFactory
val connection = factory.newConnection()
```

My docker file : -

```
FROM openjdk:8
ENV SBT_VERSION 0.13.16
RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion

WORKDIR /app
ADD target/scala-2.11/messanger-assembly-1.0.jar /app
EXPOSE 1883
CMD java -jar messanger-assembly-1.0.jar
```

The error which I am getting is as follows :-

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
web_1            |  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
web_1            |  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
web_1            |  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
web_1            |  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
web_1            |  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
web_1            |  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
web_1            |  at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)
web_1            |  at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
web_1            |  at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
web_1            |  at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:948)
web_1            |  at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:907)
web_1            |  at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:865)
web_1            |  at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1018)
web_1            |  at com.abhishek.rabbitmq.RabbitMqConnectionFactory$.<init>(RabbitMqConnectionFactory.scala:15)
web_1            |  at com.abhishek.rabbitmq.RabbitMqConnectionFactory$.<clinit>(RabbitMqConnectionFactory.scala)
```

I am not properly understanding how these variable works :-

```
hostname: localhost
environment:
  #RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
  - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER = guest
  - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS = guest
```

I kept this variable like this because by default my client is using host as localhost , user as guest and password as guest to connect to rabbitmq-server
If I am just running rabbitmq-server image with command -

```
docker-compose up --build
```

I am able to connect it through my localmachine .

Comment: share complete yml please.

Comment: edited to show complete yml file

Comment: @VinayPrajapati any idea?

Comment: If you are able to connect to it from `localhost` but not from a remote machine, then you may have a firewall rule blocking external connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to connect now. To connect to rabbit container, I need to put host as rabbit in my web container.Similarily for connection to mysql and redis , I need to use host as mysql and redis respectively.

Comment: "I need to put host as rabbit in my web container" - sorry, were you referring to `hostname`? I'm doing exactly that, but it didn't work. Actually what helped is using container name as a hostname.

Answer (score 0):

You can depend on localhost if you set network_mode for your web to "host"